# 仮想テーブルレイアウトで上下センター揃えができない。

Tags: css, html5

「仮想テーブルレイアウト」で上下センター揃えができないのですが、
以下のCSSでどこががおかしいのでしょうか？

**希望のイメージ**（上下左右#innerの中央揃え）
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

子要素の`li`に

```
display: table-cell;
```

を設定し、
親要素の`ul`に

```
display: table;
```

を設定しています。

**[index.html]**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<meta name="" content="" charset="utf-8">
</head>


<body>

<div id="inner">

<ul>
  <li><a href="">あああああ</a></li>
  <li><a href="">いいいいい</a></li>
  <li><a href="">ううううう</a></li>
</ul>

</div>

</body>
```

**[style.css]**

```css
body {
  background: #ccc;
  width: 940px;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

#inner {
  background: #aaa;
  height: 100px;
}

ul {
  display: table;
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: #896;
  width: 150px;
  border: #f94 1px solid;
}
```

ブラウザで表示すると、下の画像のようになります。
[image: 結果]

```
ul{
  height: inherit;
  display: table;
  text-align: center;
}
```

とすると以下のようになりました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 希望のイメージがよくわからないんですが、`ul`のスタイルで`height: inherit;` を指定してみたらどうでしょうか。

Comment: ありがとうございます！希望のイメージはリストを#innerの上下左右中央揃えにするということです。

Comment: やっぱりよくわらかない(table指定はulの中身の要素にであってul自体を#innerに対してではないですよね？)んですが、さらに`ul` に `margin: 0 auto;`を追加してみるとか

Comment: display: table;をどこに書くのが正しいのでしょうか？

Comment: ul自体をセル要素とするなら親要素である`<div id="inner">` だと思いますが。

Comment: ちなみに、`<!DOCTYPE html>`とは別に`<html>`を書く必要があると思います。(つまり、`<!DOCTYPE html><html>`)で、`</body>`の後に`</html>`が必要。

Comment: 確かにそうですね！ありがとうございました！

Comment: @BLUEPIXY まあHTML5では省略可能です http://www.koikikukan.com/archives/2012/09/12-015555.php

Comment: @unarist  そうかとも思ったんですがちゃんと調べずに書きました。(^_^;、まあ、ちゃんとマークアップされてないと落ち着きが悪いです。;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

テーブルセルに対する `vertical-align` は、セルの `margin` ではなく `padding` を制御するものであり、`vertical-align: middle` は**セルの中で**上下中央にするという意味です。セル自体の高さは常に行の高さに等しく、テーブルが一行で構成されていればテーブルの高さに等しくなります。

ですから、メニュー項目の高さを変えることなく上下中央にしたいのであれば、メニュー項目をセルにしてはいけません。例えばセルの中に背景やボーダーを設定した要素を置きます。

<sub>そうでなくともメニュー項目は文字の部分以外（例えば左右の余白）をクリックしても反応すべきで、そのためにリンクであるAタグでボタン全体を形作ることが多いです。</sub>

```css
body {
  background: #ccc;
  width: 940px;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

#inner {
  background: #aaa;
  height: 100px;
}

ul {
  display: table;
  text-align: center;
  height: inherit; /* ないし 100% */
}

li {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

a {
  display: block;
  background: #896;
  width: 150px;
  border: #f94 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="inner">

  <ul>
    <li><a href="">あああああ</a></li>
    <li><a href="">いいいいい</a></li>
    <li><a href="">ううううう</a></li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

もしくは、テーブル全体を別の方法で上下中央にすることになるでしょう。

Comment: できました！#innerにdisplay: table;を書き、ulにdisplay: table-cell;とvertical-align: middle;を書くことで、できました！ありがとうございます！